# how to disable all other rows EXCEPT in EDIT mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable the Edit button on all the rows when Edit button is clicked on a particular row in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449269/disable-the-edit-button-on-all-the-rows-when-edit-button-is-clicked-on-a-particul)

how to disable all other rows except the one in EDIT mode?

i am trying to find a way to disable all other row while i am in edit mode of course except the edit one.

here is my gridview looks like:

```
<gridview.... 
<edittemplate...> 
................ 
</edittemplate> 
............ 
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SelectText="Select" 
EditText="Edit" UpdateText="Save" ShowEditButton="true" /> 
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thanks for the link but i am not usign `<ItemTemplate>` i am using `<asp:CommandField`

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `RowEditing` event of GridView to disable all rows except edit one.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //Put binding code here..
        GridView1.DataBind();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex != e.NewEditIndex)
            {
                row.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

In addition to this code please verify the Page_load method's Binding code.

```
protected void Page_load()
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      //put GridView databinding code here

   } 
}
```

Comment: does not really work, i still be able to click on other rows..

Comment: @AbuHamzah I'm not aware of your code. Please show me databinding code   in page_load event.

Comment: i am using `<asp:ObjectDataSource ` for binding my gridview